# Powershell on Windows 7 Machines

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble seeing if there are any CmdLets available in Windows 7 that will allow me to add a printer remotely in PowerShell. I know Windows 8 and up has this capability but I can't find anything in PowerShell on Windows 7, even with fully updated .NET framework.

Comment: This question is probably more on-topic on [SU].

Answer (score 1):

The PrintManagement module includes these CmdLets and are Only available in Windows 8.1 and Server 2012R2 and later. These are not tied to the PowerShell version but the OS.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/%5Clibrary/Hh918357(v=WPS.630).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, unfortunately the native PowerShell cmdlets for printers are tied to the OS rather than the PowerShell version, so you'd have to go old school to script the install of printers on Windows 7 (though you can wrap it in PowerShell goodness, to execute it remotely and iterating over an OU, for example.)

Here's what we use in batch files for installing network printers:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /inf /q /n\\printserver\pnt_name
```

Set as default:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n\\printserver\pnt_name
```

and removing:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dn /q /n\\printserver\pnt_name
```

Probably possible to leverage the dll within PowerShell, but I haven't personally looked into it.